# Difference between tmux suspend and tmux detach

Tags: tmux

```
DEFAULT KEY BINDINGS
           C-z         Suspend the tmux client.
           d           Detach the current client.
```

In both cases, I leave tmux, the sessions are still available, and I can re-attach to them at any time.

Can someone highligh the differences between the 2 features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Suspending the task sends SIGSTOP which pauses the client's process but does not terminate it.

   - If you `ps wux | grep tmux` it will show up as stopped 'T'
   - You can then resume it with either `fg` which brings the latest stopped task back to the foreground, or `tmux attach`.
   - It is worth noting that `tmux attach` will connect to the first session.
   - If you have 2 sessions, one suspended and one detached, `tmux attach` without a `-t session-name` will attach to the first one in the list.
   - Using `fg`, a bash command will simply resume the last suspended task, whether that's `tmux` or not.
2. Detaching ends the client process.

   - `ps wux | grep tmux` wont show the detached session.
   - You can't resume it with `fg` but you can with `tmux attach` which creates a new client process to attach with.